# Spring Expose Controller Methods as Links

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-hateoas

I have a Group entity that represents Groups (of users) in a database. The GroupRepository class has some methods that allow me to query the Group table, like, for example:
`List<Group> findByGroupName(String name);`

This method has a URL that's exposed when I curl the URL is the immediate parent of that method, i.e.:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/groups/search/

{
    "_links" : {
        "searchNames" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/groups/search/seachNames{?terms}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "findByName" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/groups/search/findByName{?name}",
          "templated" : true
    }
}
```

I am also building a controller to add additional REST endpoints, and I want them to be exposed just like above as "_links". How do make my methods appear like so?

**UPDATE**
Here is some of my repository code.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public interface GroupRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Group, Long> {

    Group findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM `Group` WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',:terms,'%') ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = :terms THEN 0 WHEN name LIKE CONCAT(:terms,'%') THEN 1 WHEN name LIKE CONCAT('%',:terms,'%') THEN 2 WHEN name LIKE CONCAT('%',:terms) THEN 3 END",
       nativeQuery=true)
    List<Group> searchNames(@Param("terms") String terms);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the HAL representation of a resource. It's a standard.

Here is some theoretical resource : [http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

Here is the standard documented: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06

If you want to expose data as HAL, have a look at Spring HateOas and Spring Data.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

Comment: That link to the Spring guide is almost doing I want. Whenever you go to a URL, Spring responds with all child URLs under the "_links" section in the JSON object. I want the methods in my controller, which are mapped to URLs with the @RequestMapping tag to be included in that section. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right. I think it makes sense to represent the controller methods in _links section if the methods represents resources. In your example you have the resource "group" and I would say it is ok to represent this in the hateoas format.